# #1292 - Incorrect date value: '2002' for column 'fecha_inicio' at row 1

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin, I am trying to update a value in my table
[These are the current values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DRSo.png)

When executing the following statement

```
UPDATE mantenimiento SET fecha_inicio = 2022-07-13, fecha_final = 2022-07-15, id_usuario = 4, id_equipo=3, descripcion = 'Falla' WHERE id = 2;
```

I get the following error

```
#1292 - Incorrect date value: '2002' for column 'fecha_inicio' at row 1
```

I can't understand why 2002 appears to me, if in the sentence I am putting 2022

And this is my statement in php

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE mantenimiento SET fecha_inicio = :fecha_inicio, fecha_final = :fecha_final, id_usuario = :id_usuario, id_equipo=:id_equipo, descripcion = :descripcion 
                                 WHERE id = :id");
        $stmt->bindParam(':fecha_inicio', $this->fecha_inicio);
        $stmt->bindParam(':fecha_final', $this->fecha_final);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id_usuario', $this->id_usuario);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id_equipo', $this->id_equipo);
        $stmt->bindParam(':descripcion', $this->descripcion);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id);
```

Comment: You need to wrap your dates in quotes and use prepared queries. reason is 2022-07-13 = 2002 https://3v4l.org/YI0b5

Comment: @LawrenceCherone using phpmyadmin does not require use of any prepared queries.